# maven plugin as module

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

My project requires using custom Maven plugin, and I am looking for simple way to build it, preferably without messing local repository.

Let's consider simple projects tree:

```
root-project
    |---pom.xml
    |---my-library
    |       \---pom.xml
    |---my-maven-plugin
    |       \---pom.xml
    \---my-project
            \---pom.xml
```

`root-project` has three subprojects listed as `<modules>` inside. The main thing is that `my-project` uses `my-maven-plugin` during it's build process, so the plugin must be built first.

What I would like to do, is to simply run:

`root-project $  mvn package`

This should build `my-maven-plugin` first and use it during build of `my-project`.

Unfortunately, this does not work. Maven stops working during "scanning for projects..." phase, with error message:

`Unresolveable build extension: Plugin test:my-maven-plugin:1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact test:my-maven-plugin:jar:1.0`

It works if I do first

```
$ cd my-maven-plugin
$ mvn install
$ cd ..
$ mvn package
```

It does not look good. However, real problem is that the plugin depends itself on `my-library` (which is another child module of root). So, before building plugin I must enter library directory and install it. Things become worse and worse with every "internal" dependency I add to plugin. The result is mess in local repository and a lot manual steps needed to rebuild project.

Is there any way to say Maven that it should build the plugin first (with deps), and later use it during my-project building?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using profiles in your situation. You could consider two profiles in the *root-project*'s pom.xml: **build-plugin** and **build-project**. Module aggregation (<modules> list) would be **moved** to these profiles. E.g. the **build-plugin** profile would contain:

```
<modules>
   <module>my-library</module> 
   <!-- + any other "internal" dependencies needed to build the plugin -->
   <module>my-maven-plugin</module>
</modules>
```

Similarly, the **build-project** profile would contain the module list needed to build *my-project*. Then,

**mvn clean install -P build-plugin**

**mvn clean package -P build-project**

would be your commands invoking the build of *my-maven-plugin* and *my-project*, respectively. Both these commands would be executed from *root-project*'s directory. If you need to run them in sequence most of time, a simple shell script could do the work...

Comment: Just looked into the project where I had that issue and... bingo, it's exactly how I finally decided to solve problem :) I hoped for more automatic solution, but lack of other answers proves me that this is the best approach - so I am accepting your answer :)